# how do i integrate the yahoo login in my application?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

i need to integrate the yahoo login in my application using api .

Answer (score 3):

StackOverflow uses the open source "DotNetOpenAuth" to do OpenID authentication (which covers Yahoo)
http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/

Examples of use in their download.

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo uses [OpenId](http://openid.net/) for their login.  You use one of the many [libraries](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/) that are listed on their site.

Comment: If you download DotNetOpenAuth it comes with a list of examples.